# Number of ways to place chess figures on one line of chess board

Tags: combinatorics

How many ways to place chess figures of one color (2 rooks, 2 knights, 2 bishops, 1 king and 1 queen) on one line of chess board such that 2 bishops are located on the cells with different color and the king is located between 2 rooks?

Number of ways to place bishops on the cells with different color is 12. I made some by-hand calculations to get the number of ways to place the king between 2 rooks on 6 remaining cells and guess it equals 60. So overall number is 720.

Am I right?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean the king needs to be next to the rooks, or just somewhere in between?  If next to, it is a duplicate.  My answer (and it appears yours) assumes somewhere in between.

Comment: I meant "somewhere in between two rooks"

Comment: The old [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638566/chess-piece-combinations) was somewhat vague, and the asker may have been asking about positions where the rooks were right next to the kings, but [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/638566/chess-piece-combinations/638633#638633) also gave the number of positions without that artificial requirement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bishops have $16$ ways-four light squares times four dark squares.  Then if you choose three of the remaining six squares (${6 \choose 3}=20$ ways) you know where the king goes.  Now choose one of the three squares for the queen.

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad to be wrong only in my first conclusion.

Comment: I found a different number for the king and rooks as well.  That canceled with the selection of the queen square.